# What word sounds similar to "magnanimous" but means "impressively large"?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, word-usage, roots

A friend of mine often uses the word "magnanimous" to mean "large and impressive in a positive way". Examples: "Look at this magnanimous snow!" "He had a magnanimous, bushy eyebrows."

I understand this to be incorrect usage of the word. Is there a similar-sounding word, preferably with the "magnus" root, which has the meaning my friend is looking for?

Comment: _Magnificent_? _Maggot-ridden?_

Comment: Mastodontic....?

Comment: *Humongous* ... but that is a regional word.

Comment: The prefix *magni-* (or *magn-* in cases where followed by a vowel) has this meaning. You'd have to come up with the ending that basically means nothing.

Comment: _Magnum_?... :)

Comment: Eyebrows and tails are similar, in that they're both essentially *hair*. So maybe you would consider **magnicaudate**. OED says it's "Zool. Obs. rare", but the definition does seem relevant: ***Having a long tail***. There's even the derivative **magnicaudatous** - also identified as *rare*, but OED don't actually say that one is "obsolete".

Comment: To be fair, *magnanimous* does literally mean *larger than life* ... possibly a good word for body parts ;o)

Answer (score 5):

[Magnificent](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/magnificent#magnificent__4)?

> Impressively beautiful, elaborate, or extravagant; striking
>   <sub><sup>[Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com)</sup></sub>

It doesn't really imply anything about size, but it does derive from *magnus*.

Comment: This is a good suggestion, but who would mistake  magnificent , a fairly common word, with magnanimous.

Comment: @Josh61: yeah, have you read anything online lately? People encounter a word or saying that they don't know the meaning of, make an incorrect guess about its meaning based on the context, and then go off using the word with the incorrect meaning, totally convinced that they're oh-so-intelligent.

Answer (score 5):

There is (but it isn't in common use).

**Magnitudinous**: The adjectival form of *magnitude*.

> Having the quality of greatness in size, amount, importance, etc.
>   <sub><sup>[Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com)</sup></sub>

Comment: Please cite the source in your hotlink. Collins also lists the word.